# How to monitor a jar file and re-run it once it has changed?

Tags: java

**The situation:**

I deployed app.jar on a server by executing `java -jar app.jar`

**What I want to do:**

Replace app.jar and restart it automatically.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

check oracles java documents [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/deploy/getting-started.htm#GUID-12856B3D-822B-46F3-B7BE-3BE7CD71EF43)

[second link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/tools/javapackager.htm#JSWOR719)